# How to keep the Auto Clicker running without the program stopping it immediately after running

Tags: java, awtrobot

```
package com.company.Iguana;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Main {
    public static boolean Clicking = true;
    public static Robot robot;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                if(e.getKeyChar() == 'x')
                    Clicking = true;
                if(e.getKeyChar() == 'v')
                    Clicking = false;
                if(Clicking == true)
                    while(true){
                        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                robot.delay(1000);
                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            }
}
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            }


        };
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make it so whenever I press x the AutoClicker start and Stop it when I press v but once I run the code it just says **public static void main(String[] args)** but when I put in static it says 23:9
java: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
Line 23:9 is the this.addKeyListener( new KeyListener() {

..................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Do you really want most of your code to be in an Exception `catch` block?  You should fix your indentation and other formatting in any case. - also, do you mean for all this code to be in a `static` block  inside a class definition?

Comment: Is the code being inside an Exception catch block causing the problem?

Comment: I would think it might.  It isn't going to run if `new Robot()` doesn't throw an exception. - is that by design?  Do you only want that code to run if `new Robot()1` throws an exception?

Comment: I thought Exception catch block would also work so I'm guessing ima have to throw an exception instead, right?

Comment: Respectfully, I don't think you know what you're doing.  Normally, code in an exception block is there to handle an error condition.  If you want your code to run under normal conditions, then you don't want it in an. exception block.  You probably want it in a static method.  Right now, your code is all class initialization code, which isn't usual to see, although it could work.

Comment: Your code has no `main` method.  How will it actually run?  Is this code part of a bigger project?

Comment: I had a main method this code was in a different class I edited my code now and put it in the main method without a class  but once I run the code it just says public static void main(String[] args) but when I put in static it says 23:9 java: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context.// Line 23:9 is the this.addKeyListener( new KeyListener() {

Comment: See your edits.  That looks better.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the error non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context. Even after I set it to static it comes up with another error

It is talking about this.addKeyListener( new KeyListener() {

Comment: I didn't say that your code did not still have problems ;). I was just commenting on the fact that your code is no longer in an exception block, and so will run as part of normal code flow. - From what I can tell, you're having problems because you don't know the language well enough.  You should understand the difference between static and non-static contexts.  The former is where global variables live...variables that there are only a single instance of.  non-static variables are variables that exist for each object of a particular class.

Comment: I suggest that you read over this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-static-and-non-static-variables-in-java/

Comment: I kind of fixed it, it no longer gives me the error but it still ends with Process finished with exit code 0. What I'm trying to figure out is how to keep the Auto Clicker running.. I edited the new code if needed

Comment: I believe the while loop is supposed to keep it running but its just stopping immediately after running

Comment: You're creating a `KeyListener`, but you're not passing or assigning it to anything.  How do you expect any of the code in that object to ever be called?  What I see is code that creates a `Robot`, creates a `KeyListener`, and then exits.

Comment: If you did manage to get the line `robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);` to run, it's going to run over and over again as rapidly as possible...forever.  How do you see that being useful?

Comment: KeyListener creates the methods so I'm basically assigning them to the methods not sure what else to do. The auto clicker is part of a simple project, don't worry about it.

Comment: The only way that your code could do anything is if the act of creating a `KeyListener` object not only registered itself somewhere, but then caused a main event loop to start up and run to keep your program running. I doubt very much that that's what is going on here.  If the `Robot` and `KeyListener` objects were somehow tied together at creation time, then I might think that the `Robot` object contained an event loop or something.  But they don't know about each other until the `KeyListener` handles a keypress, which I can't see it ever doing since it isn't hooked to anything.

Comment: I've been doing this for many years.  When you create some kind of listener, you somehow always associate it with a main application, either by having some reference to that app passed in at creation time, or by taking the reference to the newly created object and passing it into the main app so that it gets registered and does something.  Here, you're not doing either of those.  There is no main app.  Where do you think the code is that runs and keeps your app alive after it has created the two objects? - Your app creates two objects and then quits.  I'm pretty sure that's all that happens.